# How to use Like and another function or field from a form in Access?

Tags: ms-access, sql-like

I have a drop-down menu in a form where you choose the year from pre-entered values. That field is used in different queries to display different data depending on the year you've chosen from the drop down menu ([Field]).

I would like to use this field in a query with the Like operator an a Wild card character.

I have the form open and the value of the [Form]![SubForm]![Field] equals for example 2018. If I try `Like "*2018"` it works fine.

I tried this but it doesn't work: `Like "*[Form]![SubForm]![Field]"`

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: With no testing try `Like "*" & [Form]![SubForm]![Field]`.  At the moment the form reference is just text so it's trying to find something like _[Form]![SubForm]![Field]_  rather than the value the control holds.

Comment: Try saving the value of `[Form]![SubForm]![Field]` in a variable, and then use it later in your sentence. Something like  `MyVar = [Form]![SubForm]![Field] ` and later on `Like "*" & MyVar`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes! This worked. I tried previously with `Like "*" And [Form]![SubForm]![Field]` but that didn't work. "&" does the trick. Thanks! EDIT: How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: You can't - I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is taking the text as is.
`Like "*[Form]![SubForm]![Field]"` is searching for text that is like `[Form]![SubForm]![Field]`.

You need to look for text that is like the contents of the control, not the reference to the control:
`Like "*" & [Form]![SubForm]![Field]`

The code above concatenates `*` with the value held in the control.